# Could not find artifact com.vico:com.vico.spring.boot.starter.service

Tags: spring, maven, jenkins, spring-boot

i am setting up new jobs with jenkins 2 and i get the following error at my compiling stage:

```
[INFO] --------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] --------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 33.893s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Aug 19 08:38:57 CEST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/111M
[INFO] --------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project xy: Could not resolve dependencies for project xy:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.vico:com.vico.spring.boot.starter.service:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in jcenter-snapshots (https://jcenter.bintray.com/) -> [Help 1]
```

I dont get why it has problems compiling the code (it does not in my old jenkins and neither at my locale station)

```
stage('Compile Stage') {
    sh 'mvn clean compile'
}
```

my pom entries look like:

```
<name>xy</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vico</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.vico.spring.boot.starter.service</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
etc....
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is?

thx

Comment: Do you use a custom Maven repository? I couldn't find that spring boot starter artifact anywhere in public Maven repositories, so i assume that. In that case check your Maven settings, if they include your custom Maven repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try run mvn with -x option in both servers , maybe the settings.xml is not the same

Comment: SOLUTION: i had to configure my own settings.xml under /etc/maven/settings.xml to include the dependency